# redirect to a url after sliding up content

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(".removeall").dblclick(function () { 
                $(this).parent().slideUp(); 
                });
```

What I want to happen now, using jquery, is to redirect to main.php after this is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".removeall").dblclick(function(){
    // The slideUp function takes two parameters, a 'speed' for the animation, and
    // a callback method to be called once the animation is done.
    $(this).parent().slideUp("fast", function(){
        window.location = "/main.php";
    });
});
```

You can read more about the slideUp method [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).